# List of sketches disappears off the bottom of my screen

Tags: library, sketch

v 2:1.0.5

The list of sketches disappears off the bottom of my screen and there is no scroll to reach them. This renders the IDE nearly useless.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Yes. Install a version of the IDE that isn't 10 years old.

Comment: There are several IDE for Arduino, do you know? Like UECIDE, for example.

Comment: get a bigger screen, or move some into a sub-folder

Answer (score 1):

That issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/commit/49a05121d442a2af1280876887943b1a014f2adf) since the Arduino IDE 1.5.5 [release](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/releases/tag/1.5.5), 4 years ago.

The version of the Arduino IDE you get from `apt-get install arduino` has not been able to be updated for years due to [licensing issues](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2703). The versions available from various package managers may also be modified in ways that introduce new bugs. For this reason you should always install the official Arduino IDE version downloaded from:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software